# WebServer and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, webserver

I'm writing a web server in java, and when the browser sends a string (with GET or POST) with accented characters (for example à è ì ò ù) the server receives strange symbols.
I think I should use UTF-8 encoding, but I don't know how.
Can you suggest to me a solution? (it's ok both client/server side)
Thank you in advice!

**[EDIT]**
I'm using InputStreamReader on the web server. I did a test sending "àèìòù" and sniffing the http packet with wireshark:

`Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n`
...
`text=%E8%E0%EC%F2%F9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the input stream from the socket using an [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) which is constructed with `"UTF-8"` as 2nd argument. But if the client specified a `charset` in the `Content-Type` request header, then you should use that instead.

Comment: Actually, that won’t work right because you don’t get an exception on illegal UTF-8. The second argument needs to be `Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()`.

Comment: @tchrist what is "The second argument"?

Comment: @thrist: can also. @supergiox: of the `InputStreamReader`. As to your question edit, the `Accept-Charset` request header does not represent the encoding of the query string. You should not assume it to be the query string encoding. It's to be specified by `Content-Type` request header which lot of clients indeed omit. Webbrowsers usually use the charset of the `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response of the page which delivers the form or the link.

Comment: @BalusC I tried with that second argument, but no news... the Content-Type header is: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Ah, it's a POST request? Use the same charset as the page with the form was been delivered with, that's the charset which you specified in the `Content-Type` header of the response of that page. The string `%E8%E0%EC%F2%F9` is clearly ISO-8859-1 by the way.

Comment: Also with `br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1").newDecoder()));` nothing seems change :(

Comment: `System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode("%E8%E0%EC%F2%F9", "ISO-8859-1"));` gives here `èàìòù`. Note that you shouldn't confuse request body encoding with request parameter encoding.

Comment: Thank you! In another class of my app i was using URLDecoder with utf-8. I changed it into ISO-8859-1 and now it works!

Comment: You're welcome. Only make sure that you don't hardcode it. If the client specified any charset in `Content-Type` request header, you should use that instead.

Comment: Now I've only problems sending "+", because it's understood as space.. but perhaps I should open a new question!?

Comment: The `+` is indeed decoded into a space. That's perfectly valid. If the client want to send an actual `+`, it should properly encode it first. Like as all decent webbrowsers do.

Comment: Ok, I solved also the problem with `+`... another stupid error! thank you very much :)